# Solve molecular structure in python using individual atoms

Tags: python, list, loops

I have this 2D-list:

```
list1 = [['Number', 'Atom', 'Bond to', 'Dist from X', 'Atomtype'],
[0, 'C', [1, 21, 22], [], []],
[1, 'C', [0, 2, 7, 8], [], []],
[2, 'C', [1, 3, 9, 10], [], []],
[3, 'C', [2, 4, 11, 12], [], []],
[4, 'C', [3, 5, 13, 14], [], []],
[5, 'C', [4, 6, 15, 16], [], []],
[6, 'C', [5, 17, 18, 19], [], []],
[7, 'H', [1], [], []],
[8, 'H', [1], [], []],
[9, 'H', [2], [], []],
[10, 'H', [2], [], []],
[11, 'H', [3], [], []],
[12, 'H', [3], [], []],
[13, 'H', [4], [], []],
[14, 'H', [4], [], []],
[15, 'H', [5], [], []],
[16, 'H', [5], [], []],
[17, 'H', [6], [], []],
[18, 'H', [6], [], []],
[19, 'H', [6], [], []],
[20, 'H', [21], [], []],
[21, 'O', [0, 20], [], []],
[22, 'O', [0], [], []]]
```

This represents a molecule. The first column is just a number, second column represents an atom in the molecule (C=carbon, H=hydrogen, O=oxygen). The third column tells where this atom is bond to. For example atom 0 has a bond with atoms 1, 21 and 22. The heteroatom (either one of the oxygens) is labelled as X-atom (its atomtype is X). I want to find out how many bonds away each atom is from the X-atom and I also want to find out atomtypes for carbons. If carbon has one bond to other carbons, it has atomtype E (end of the chain). If carbon has two bonds to other carbons, it has atomtype C, three bonds is T and carbon that has four bonds to other carbons, is Q-type. So this list should look like:

```
list1 = [['Number', 'Atom', 'Bond to', 'Dist from X', 'Atomtype'],
[0, 'C', [1, 21, 22], [1], [E]],
[1, 'C', [0, 2, 7, 8], [2], [C]],
[2, 'C', [1, 3, 9, 10], [3], [C]],
[3, 'C', [2, 4, 11, 12], [4], [C]],
[4, 'C', [3, 5, 13, 14], [5], [C]],
[5, 'C', [4, 6, 15, 16], [6], [C]],
[6, 'C', [5, 17, 18, 19], [7], [E]],
[7, 'H', [1], [2], [-]],
[8, 'H', [1], [2], [-]],
[9, 'H', [2], [3], [-]],
[10, 'H', [2], [3], [-]],
[11, 'H', [3], [4], [-]],
[12, 'H', [3], [4], [-]],
[13, 'H', [4], [5], [-]],
[14, 'H', [4], [5], [-]],
[15, 'H', [5], [6], [-]],
[16, 'H', [5], [6], [-]],
[17, 'H', [6], [7], [-]],
[18, 'H', [6], [7], [-]],
[19, 'H', [6], [7], [-]],
[20, 'H', [21], [1], [-]],
[21, 'O', [0, 20], [0], [X]],
[22, 'O', [0], [2], [-]]]
```

This molecule represents heptanoic acid. I tried to solve the distances like this:

```
for sublist1 in list1:
    if sublist1[0] != "C" and sublist1[0] != "H":
        start = sublist1[0] #number of the heteroatom
j = 1 #j is essentially the distance from the heteroatom
for sublist2 in list1:
    if sublist2[1] == "C":
        if start in sublist2[2]:
            sublist2[3].append(j)
        j += 1
        start = sublist5[0]
```

But this did not work. How can I solve the distances and atomtypes?

Answer (score 1):

For the carbon atom types you can use the following code snippet.

```py
carbon_atom_types = ['-', 'E', 'C', 'T' ,'Q']

for atom_info in list1:
    if atom_info[1] == 'C':
        bonds_to_atoms = atom_info[2]
        carbon_atoms = 0
        
        for atom in bonds_to_atoms:
            if list1[atom+1][1] == 'C':
                carbon_atoms += 1
        
        atom_info[4] = carbon_atom_types[carbon_atoms]
```

If you have control over how the list1 is structured, it might be useful to use a list of dictionaries where you can look up information such as atom type, distance to X, etc, using a key. or use a pandas dataframe.

P.S. If you could explain how the Oxygen heteroatom is chosen I will answer the other part as well. In the example, you provided, `list1`  does not have any heteroatom as there is no oxygen with atom type X.

Comment: If there is only one heterotom, it is the X-type atom. But since here are 2 oxygens, the heteroatom can be either one of them. It doesn't really matter which one it is, just choose one of them. It could be done with a loop. I tried to do this with some kind of loop. I looked at row[1] for each row in list1 and if row[1] != "C" and row[1] !="H", then row[4] = "X". But this assings "X" to both of the oxygens. If only you could figure out how I can assign only one of the oxygens to "X", it would be really helpful. Thanks a lot for your comment, it was helpful!